# Give an arguments to main

Tags: java, arguments

When i give a name of Class in args to main , an argument is :
"myPackage.Algo.PersonneA". I have an exception and i don't know why ?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   myPackage.Algo.PersonneA

This is my main :

> ```
>  public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Algo rf = (Algo) Class.forName(args[0]).newInstance();
>
>     }
> ```

and this is a class what i want instanciate in main.

> ```
> package myPackage;
> public class Algo {
>      public static class PersonneA extends ClassA {
>         public Algorithm create(int r) {
>             return new AlgorithmDist(new DistributedDocument(), r);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static class PersonneB extends ClassA {
>         public Algorithm create(int r) {
>             return new AlgorithmSimul(new SimulationDocument(), r);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

(1) for inner class, you need to pass to `forName()` the string:

```
"myPackage.Algo$PersonneA"
               ^
           instead of .
```

The inner class is seperated from the enclosing class with a `$` and not with a `.`.

So change the argument to `main()` to the above string instead the one you provided.

(2)  `PersonneA` is subclass of `ClassA` and not of `Algo` - so after fixing issue 1 you will still get a `ClassCastException`, since an object of type `PersonneA` is not of type `Algo`

Answer (score 1):

your main should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Algo rf = (Algo) Class.forName(args[0]).newInstance();

    }
```

you wrote: `static public void main(String[] args)` which is wrong syntax :)

Comment: This is wrong. If the problem was a syntax error he would have got a compile time error. he gets a run time error.

Comment: Alright, it might have something to do with your package then. Is your Algo class a inner class of your main, or is your main in a own java file? Make sure that your java files start with: package myPackage; (if they are placed in that package)